# Power Query Help in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am working in Power Query with normalized tables in Power BI, and need to manipulate a table in order to create a many-to-one relationship to another table. Consider the following example. I have a table with the columns "Employee ID", "Metric", and "Value". Each employee ID has the "Metrics" Name, Gender, Age, Department, and Experience. Currently, the table is structured so that each Employee ID is repeated 5 times, one for each metric, and has a value for each in the "Value" column.

I need to pivot the data so that each unique Employee ID has a row, with separate columns for each metric, and the Values in the corresponding cells. 
Each employee ID will have a row, and the columns will be "Name", "Gender", "Age", "Department", and "Experience". Is there an easy way to do this in Power Query in Power BI?

I tried a pivot, and this creates the columns as desired, but still repeats the Employee IDs. For example, each employee will be listed in a row, and the "Name" column will be filled. All of the employee IDs will be listed a second time in the "Employee ID" column, but now the "Name" column will be blank, and only "Gender" will be populated. And this continues for all metrics

Any help is much appreciated. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Does the table have a unique ID column? It sounds to me like it's trying to pivot but there are other column(s) that are preventing it from combining the rows like you want.

Comment: Hi Alex, the ID column is unique in that each Employee ID will only have one value for each metric. The Employee IDs are duplicated for each row though. I have been using the solution below but it does not seem work correctly, as I am still getting the same result with the Metrics as columns, but the Employee ID repeated in a new row for each different Metric.

Comment: A more detailed description can be seen in the comment below.

Comment: The table does have another unique ID column! It needed to be deleted before the pivot worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Transform, select the Column Metric and press Pivot.. (Draaikolom in Dutch)
[image]

You get a popup, select Value as your Value Column.

[image]

Result is not yet what you want:
[image]

Go to Advanced table Editor (under start tab). Remove the List.Count (including comma)

[image]
Press ok, end result is what you are looking for:

[image]

Comment: Hi Aldert, thank you for your response! It looks like your code for removing the List.Count got cut off, would it be possible to copy and paste? Thank you again.

Comment: When you follow the steps, it should become clear. There is no intent thah you need the code. You should see in your advanced editor where to remove the List.Count.

Comment: I see the List.Count now. I have another problem, though. When I do the initial pivot, I do not get ones across the row as is shown in your example. Each Employee ID Is repeated 5 times, once for each Metric, and there is only a value in the column that corresponds to that metric. For example, Employee ID 1 would be repeated 5 times. The first row only has a value in the "Name" column, the other columns are 0. The next only has a value in the "Gender" column (for the same Employee ID), and the remaining columns are 0, etc.

Comment: Please follow steps exactly, most likely you selected the wrong column.

Comment: Thank you! The process worked, but I did not realize I had another column with a unique timestamp that needed to be removed as well.

Comment: Excellent, glad I could help!